# how to solve this kind of errors

Tags: csv, import, jupyter

```py
data  = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Sgrids\OneDrive - Smart Grid Analytics pvt ltd\backup\Documents\Dhinesh D\CSBPL Alerts EDA\CSBPL_alerts.xlsx")
^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I was trying to read the csv file, but it was showing me this error.

Comment: Did you notice that you are reading what appears to be an Excel 2007 (XLSX) format as csv (plain text). They are not the same, even if Excel by defaults will open the CSV as a spreadsheet. Technically XLSX are zip files with the sheets and resources inside.